# Which football matches had the highest combined number of goals?

Tags: football, records, fifa, english-premier-league, la-liga

I would like to know football match with highest number goals scored for both teams combined in both international football, and the top European leagues like the English Premier League, La Liga etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

International match: Australia hold the record for the most goals in an international match for a victory over American Samoa (11th April 2001) in Oceanian 2002 World Cup qualifiers. Australia 31 vs Samoa 0 with combined total of 31.

Sources: [goalprofits](https://www.goalprofits.com/most-goals-scored-in-a-football-match/), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4c3zaQrncc), [CBC SPORTS](http://www.cbc.ca/sports/soccer/australians-set-world-cup-soccer-scoring-record-1.254320), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_31%E2%80%930_American_Samoa)

World Cup Match: Austria v Switzerland (1954) combined goal scored 12 with Austria 7 vs Switzerland 5

Sources: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria_v_Switzerland_(1954_FIFA_World_Cup)), [FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=212/match=1237/index.html), [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI6jQUV2ch8)

English Premier League: Portsmouth 7 vs Reading 4 for combined total of 11 in 29th September 2007

Sources: [whoateallthepies](http://www.whoateallthepies.tv/portsmouth/223260/on-this-day-in-2007-highest-scoring-premier-league-match-ever-as-portsmouth-thump-reading-7-4.html), [skysports](http://www.skysports.com/football/portsmth-vs-reading/88967), [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/eng_prem/7008200.stm), [therawstraw](http://therawstraw.com/premier-league-at-its-best/)

Champions League: Borussia Dortmund 8 vs Legia Warsaw 4 for combined 12 goals in 22/11/2016.

Sources: [DW](http://www.dw.com/en/champions-league-records-tumble-as-ruthless-borussia-dortmund-put-eight-past-legia-warsaw/a-36486715), [dailymail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4247538/Manchester-City-set-Champions-League-leg-tie-record.html)

La Liga: Athletic Bilbao 9 vs Racing Santander 5 (5 February 1933) with combined total of 14

Sources: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_records_in_Spain), [espn](http://www.espn.in/football/uefa-champions-league/2/blog/post/3002639/footballs-biggest-scorelines-from-world-cup-to-premier-league-via-mls)

Bundesliga: With combined total of 12,

- Borussia Mönchengladbach 12–0 Borussia Dortmund (matchday 34 of 1977–78)
- Borussia Dortmund 11–1 Arminia Bielefeld (1982–83)
- Bayern Munich 11–1 Borussia Dortmund (1971–72)
- Borussia Dortmund 9–3 1. FC Kaiserslautern (1963–64)
- 1. FC Köln 8–4 Tennis Borussia Berlin (1976–77)

Sources: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundesliga_records#Goals_2), [bundesliga](http://www.bundesliga.com/de/bundesliga/news/top-fact-kuriose-rekorde-der-bundesliga-noblsp.jsp)

Serie A: AC Milan 9 vs Atalanta 3, 1972/1973, for a combined total of 12

Sources: [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistiche_della_Serie_A#Record_risultati), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6lBzZfrrvU), [thegentlemanultra](http://www.thegentlemanultra.com/gazzetta/dissecting-the-great-feast-ac-milan-vs-atalanta-197273)

Ligue 1: Sochaux 12 vs Valenciennes 1, 1935–36 for combined total of 13

Sources: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ligue_1_records_and_statistics), [footballdatabase](http://www.footballdatabase.eu/football.match.sochaux.valenciennes.66323.en.html)

**Update**

Scottish Cup: Arbroath 36 vs Bon Accord 0 for combined total of 36 in 1885/86

Sources: [goalprofits](https://www.goalprofits.com/most-goals-scored-in-a-football-match/), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbroath_36%E2%80%930_Bon_Accord)

UEFA Cup Winners' Cup: Sporting Club de Portugal 16 vs APOEL FC 1 for a combined total of 17 in 13/11/63, European Cup Winners' Cup first round first leg

Source: [UEFA](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2231480.html), [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-No4Ii0iGw)

FA Cup: Preston North End 26 vs Hyde United 0 for combined total of 26 in 1887

Sources: [bleacherreport](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1488110-the-7-worst-blowouts-in-soccer-history)

---

Some website shows Australia win over Samoa as 32-0.

I'm not sure about Ligue 1 that was the biggest one that I have found.

Comment: According to [italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistiche_della_Serie_A#Record_risultati) the Serie A match with more goals is Milan-Atalanta 9-3 (total 12 goals) played on  [15/10/1972](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_A_1972-1973)

Answer (score 3):

There is also a relevant case: [Federated States of Micronesia national under-23 football team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_States_of_Micronesia_national_under-23_football_team).

> Their performance was the worst recorded in international football as they lost all three games, conceding 114 goals (an average of 38 goals each game) in the process without scoring themselves. On two occasions, against Fiji and Vanuatu, they conceded a record number of goals in international competition. However, although these matches count as official records for the Pacific Games, since the games did not involve senior teams, they will not be recognised by FIFA as official world records. Despite the unofficial nature of their record defeats, numerous international media outlets have branded them the worst football team on the planet.

- Micronesia 0 - 30 Tahiti (3 July 2015)
- Micronesia 0 - 38 Fiji (5 July 2015)
- Micronesia 0 - 46 Vanuatu (7 July 2015)

So in this case, the highest combined number of goals was 46 (46+0).

Comment: @Nij I brought the debate to Meta: [How should we format results?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/811/11439).

Answer (score 3):

I find [this match](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/africa/2386609.stm) that seems the world record with 149 goals during a single match.

The results is caused by a protest on a refereeing decisions.
All the 149 were caused by deliberately own goals.

It is possible to find info about this match also on Wikipedia's article [AS Adema 149–0 SO l'Emyrne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS_Adema_149%E2%80%930_SO_l%27Emyrne):

> AS Adema 149–0 SO I'Emyrne was an association football match played on 31 October 2002 between two teams in Antananarivo, Madagascar. It holds the world record for the highest scoreline, recognized by The Guinness Book of Records. SO l'Emyrne intentionally lost the game against their arch-rivals AS Adema in protest over refereeing decisions that had gone against them during a four-team playoff tournament. The match surpassed the previous record for the highest scoreline of 36–0, set in 1885.